# Looking for (wxPython) Python 2D drawing framework

Tags: python, wxpython, 2d

I'm looking for a framework for drawing 2D scenes in Python.  Not for game programming, but for 'office' like applications (e.g. drawing diagrams, mindmaps etc).

Preferable something that can be used with wxPython.

wxPython comes with OGL, but that is very old and no-one seems to use it any more (I couldn't find a reference to it in any recent project in sourceforge or google code).

The Qt (PyQt) framework has the Scenegraph thing, which I've used in some C++ projects, but I think PyQt with the Qt dependencies is too big.

Requirements are :
- managing objects
- hit-testing of objects
- ability to print the scenes
- modern look (at least anti-aliasing of lines)

I've been looking for some days now, but can't find anything that even comes close to PyQt's Scenegraph.  I've been thinking about modifying OGL to use a wxGraphicsContext...

P.S. Anyone using OGL, please shout 'OGL is not dead' :-)

Comment: http://www.pygame.org/project-Pygame+embedded+in+wxPython-1580-.html  perhaps?

Comment: Hmm... I don't see how PyGame would fit.  Its documentation doesn't really provide a good overview.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use floatcanvas for this. Joran mentioned PyGame, which is certainly a legitimate option. I would also take a look at the WhyteBoard project (https://code.google.com/p/whyteboard/) which is written in wxPython and does a few of the items you mentioned. Finally, wxPython supports Cairo, which you also might find helpful. There are several demos of Cairo in the wxPython demo. By the way, wx.GraphicsContext (which you had mentioned) supports anti-aliasing, as does Cairo.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the suggestions.
Cairo seems like another library to write things to a device context (or surface).  As far as I can see from the documentation, it has no API for maintaining a 'scene' with objects.
Whyteboard is indeed interesting.  Maybe I can get the canvas.py and tools.py out of the application to keep just the drawing functionality.
wx.GraphicsContext indeed supports anti-aliasing, bug OGL doesn't use that.
Regards,
Marc

Comment: Just found the FloatCanvas demo.  Seems a bit similar to OGL, but seems to be actively maintained.  No anti-aliasing out-of-the-box though, however there are sample on how to subclass your own object and us sxGraphicsContext.  Thanks !

Comment: Just realized I would also need rotation and scaling of individual objects.  So e.g. I could have a rotated text box.  This isn't supported in any framework I've found so far. :-(  wxGraphicsContext supports transformations, it may be possible to take advantage of that if I write my own framework (which I would prefer to avoid).

Comment: Did you ask on the float canvas list if they had any idea? Or even on the wxPython list? Those guys have done a LOT of these things.

Comment: Hi Mike, do you mean the google groups wxpython-users list ? Floatcanvas only seems to have an E-mailing list, which I prefer to avoid.  I've searched through both to see how much they are being used, but haven't asked a question yet.  Will post 1 on the google groups one.  Thanks for the pointer.  Marc

Comment: The google group will work too. The people who are behind the floatcanvas project are also there.